# Tap gesture recognizer added to UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift

I've the following code to add a gesture recognizer to a UILabel. User Interaction Enabled is ticked on for the label in the storyboard, but when I tap on the label the onUserClickingSendToken method is not being called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tokenDisplay: UILabel!
    var tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:  #selector(onUserClickingSendToken(_:)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tokenDisplay.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func onUserClickingSendToken(_ sender: Any)
    {
      ....
```

Comment: Make sure its property userInteraction is set to true. It's default is false. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620543-isuserinteractionenabled

Comment: I've added a line tokenDisplay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true to make sure but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I already have a breakpoint and an NSLog in it to check its not being called.

Comment: It already is. I've used tap gesture recognizers many many times before, totally mystified why this isn't working. So much so that I've given up and using a button instead.Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Initializing the tapRecognizer in viewDidLoad should do it, cause you were targeting self before the view was initialized

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tokenDisplay: UILabel!
var tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:      #selector(onUserClickingSendToken(_:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tokenDisplay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tokenDisplay.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func onUserClickingSendToken(_ sender: Any)
{
  ....
```

Comment: tapGestureRecognizer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true 
This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In general for UILabel clickable issue:

There are couple of reasons why your UILabel will not work as clickable

1. Make sure to mark UILabel UserInteraction true and if yourLabel is inside other view than mark that view UserInteraction true too.

> yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

2. Assigning self to target before the view initialisation, move your code inside viewDidLoad/awakeFromNib or after view Load

> let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickLabel(_:)))
> self.yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

3. If you are adding UILabel programmatically, than you have to assign it's frame too.

> yourLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20)

4. Super view in which your UILabel is should be large enough to fit/display label properly, if your label is inside some view than that view's height/weight should assign in a way that it cover the whole UILabel frame.

> In my case this was the problem I had, I tried so many thing but at last it turns out that the view in which I had my label had fixed width, the label was displaying properly but onClick event was't working due to out of frame.

[image]

> It was missing UILabel's trailing constraints, so half of the thing is not clickable.

5. Using same tab gesture for multiple view, you cannot use one tab gesture for more than one view or labels,use different for each UILabel.

   try this:

   ```
   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickLabel(_:)))
   self.yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true           
   self.yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

   let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickLabel(_:)))
   self.someView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true        
   self.someView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)
   ```

   instead of this:

   ```
   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClickLabel(_:)))
   self.yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true            
   self.yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)        
   self.someView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   self.someView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)      
   // tapGesture will work on only one element
   ```

Comment: Another case to take into consideration is when there is a view infront. In that case, the view infront must set isUserInteractionEnabled to false

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selector setup to:

`#selector(ViewController .onUserClickingSendToken(_:)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its not having an effect however